# How to Implement inner join in ydn-db?

Tags: indexeddb, ydn-db

I need to implement an inner join on two tables `order_header` and `order_item` based on their `ORDER_ID`. The equivalent SQL query:
`SELECT * FROM order_header INNER JOIN order_item ON order_header.ORDER_ID=order_item.ORDER_ID` How to implement this in ydn-db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`db.scan`](http://dev.yathit.com/api/ydn/db/storage.html#scan) for table joining. Currently YDN-DB does not have a nice wrapper for joining, but [manual joining](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/doc/query/join-query.html) is not that difficult. Here is joining query for `SELECT * FROM Supplier, Part WHERE Supplier.CITY = Part.CITY`.

```
var iter_supplier = new ydn.db.IndexValueIterator('Supplier', 'CITY');
var iter_part = new ydn.db.IndexValueIterator('Part', 'CITY');
var req = db.scan(function(keys, values) {
  var SID = keys[0];
  var PID = keys[1];
  console.log(SID, PID);
  if (!SID || !PID) {
    return []; // done
  }
  var cmp = ydn.db.cmp(SID, PID); // compare keys
  if (cmp == 0) {
    console.log(values[0], values[1]);
    return [true, true]; // advance both
  } else if (cmp == 1) {
    return [undefined, SID]; // jump PID cursor to match SID
  } else {
    return [PID, undefined]; // jump SID cursor to match PID
  }
}, [iter_supplier, iter_part]);
```

See more detail on [Join query article](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/doc/query/join-query.html).